# When a matrix can be similar to a Jordan normal form

Tags: linear-algebra

I have learned about diagonalize matrices, a matrix can be diagonalize iff the geometric multiplicity is equal to algebraic multiplicity.
When can a matrix be similar to Jordan normal form matrix?

Comment: Every complex matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Complex_matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is always, provided that one is working over an algebraically closed field (like $\Bbb C$) or at least willing to work with matrices whose entries might be in a suitable finite extension of one's starting field.

More precisely:

Given an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ over a field $\Bbb F$ there is a Jordan normal form matrix $J$ and an invertible matrix $P$, both over $\Bbb F$, such that $A = PJP^{-1}$ iff all of the eigenvalues of $A$ are in $\Bbb F$.

The eigenvalues of $A$ are the roots of the polynomial $\det(\lambda \Bbb I - A)$, whose coefficients are in $\Bbb F$, and hence the eigenvalues are all contained in the algebraic closure $\bar{\Bbb F}$ of $\Bbb F$. Thus, there is always a Jordan normal form matrix $\bar{J}$ and an invertible matrix $\bar{P}$, both over $\bar{\Bbb F}$, such that $A = \bar{P} \bar{J} \bar{P}^{-1}$, and in particular a matrix over an algebraically closed field (like $\Bbb C$) is always similar to a Jordan normal form matrix.